# How to change the white color of the still loading portion of an image?

Tags: css, userscripts

I like browsing sites at night and sometimes a slowly loading image displays a large solid white color area, which will soon be filled with the rest of the image when it finishes loading, but while it does so, my eyes get blinded with bright white light. Especially if the image is large and loads very slowly.

I'm talking about the case where the image is being shown as it loads, which is the case with `<img src="image_uri_here" />`. In case of  `<div style="background: url('image_uri_here')">` the image is not shown at all until it loads completely (and it adds other problems). I still want to be able to see the image while it is loading, so moving from the `img` to `div` approach is not a desirable solution.

So I want to have some control of the white area's color via CSS or by moving around the elements in some special way via a userscript. The least I would like to be able to do is change the color to black. The best option would be to make it transparent. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

So far I have not been able to find a better solution than to use a CSS filter matrix to achieve this. I cannot explain how this works, but it turns the white color into transparent color, and the color of this area can be controlled by `background-color` property of the `<img>` element. This doesn't appear to key out pure white color in the image itself. Also, this has a great CPU cost, so I would appreciate a much less CPU-hungry way to achieve the same result.

Here is the filter code:

```
<svg class="defs-only">
    <filter id="makeWhiteLoadingPartTransparent">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
1   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   1" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Add `style="filter:url('#makeWhiteLoadingPartTransparent')"` to elements you wish to affect with this.

Answer (score 1):

if you set `background-color` for image style - it does exactly that currently in stable Chrome version 93 (but not in firefox)